# Which ports are open at http://aspmx.l.google.com?

Tags: g-suite, mx-record

When I try a Nmap scan it shows that all ports all filtered, but how does this domain ( aspmx.l.google.com  ) suppose handle all the mails if all ports are closed, when using Google Apps for businesses?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25
Trying 173.194.67.26...
Connected to aspmx.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP z8si11438427wix.13
```

Port 25 is open to receive email via SMTP.

Your nmap result is wrong and you should be aware of the [legalities of port scanning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner#Legal_implications) since it's a grey area in some places. Potentially, Googled detected it, and blocked you.

Comment: Only port 25 is open? What about POP?

Comment: `aspmx.l.google.com` is designated for inbound mail only - that's why it's used in MX records (for other servers to push emails through to). Use `pop.gmail.com` (POP/IMAP) or `smtp.gmail.com` (SMTP) if you're configuring your clients so they can retrieve it.

Comment: Ok, so it would not be any problem if I would use my own (non-Google and non-Postini) server for the primary MX record (priority =1) and only forward port 25 to aspmx.l.google.com?

Comment: I can't imagine it'd be a wise idea to be honest: all inbound emails will now have their source IP as your server, which may cause SPF records to bounce: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework. This would leave an awful lot of emails in your spam box.

Comment: @JayShah, having an inbound gateway is supported, but for the best add some settings in your Google Apps control panel.  http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60730